# Google Service Account (SA) key for Cloud Storage files too long

Tags: authentication, go, google-cloud-platform, .env

I am trying to authenticate with Google Service Account (SA) key that I got from the Google cloud console. It does not contain any spaces.

In  my .env I have

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='{"type":"service_account","project_id":"xyz"...}'
```

Then the code is

```
func GetSignedURL(w io.Writer) error {
    customEndpoint := "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket-name/o"
    ctx := context.Background()
    fmt.Println(len(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")))//<--2303

    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithEndpoint(customEndpoint))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())//<--file name too long 
    }
    defer client.Close()

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "The request endpoint set for the client is: %v\n", customEndpoint)
    return nil
}
```

The gcloud I'm using is:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 412.0.0
alpha 2022.12.09
beta 2022.12.09
bq 2.0.83
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.12.09
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.17
minikube 1.28.0
skaffold 2.0.3
```

I get the error `dialing: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: open {"type": "service_account","project_id":"xyz"...}: file name too long`

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: The wrong idea is to use a service account key file. Are you sure you need it? Most of the time, you don't need it. And it's most secure to do without. Anyway, your issue is the following: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must reference a file, not the content of the file.